# Can we join CDF and Survival function in Copula

Tags: statistics

Can we join CDF(cumulative density function) and Survival function like this in copula construction

$$
H\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)=Pr\left(X_1<x_1,X_2>x_2,X_3<x_3\right)
$$
or 
$$
H\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)=C\left(F_1\left(x_1\right), 1-F_2\left(x_2\right),F_3\left(x_3\right)\right)$$
or
$$H\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right)=C\left(F_1\left(x_1\right), S_2\left(x_2\right),F_3\left(x_3\right)\right) $$

Comment: This is neither about distributions as covered by the tag *distribution-theory*, not about *multi-valued functions* (used in complex analysis) as far as I can see. I can understand why the former tag was used (it's a common confusion), but not why the latter tag was used.